# Call to a Member Function on String (But Function Returns String) PHP

Tags: php, string

I'm creating a menu script to streamline my website development, but I've landed into a problem. No articles I've looked through SO or not have not been helpful. Essentially what this script is supposed to do is that it is comprised of several custom "buttons" (`class Button`) inside the Menu (`class Menu`).

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_button() on string in F:\Imagine\Youth Group Connect\Site\php\Menu.php:17 Stack trace: #0 F:\Imagine\Youth Group Connect\Site\users\login.php(148): Menu->get() #1 {main} thrown in F:\Imagine\Youth Group Connect\Site\php\Menu.php on line 17`

The function get_button() returns a string, so does anyone have any idea why PHP would be throwing this error? Here's from `Menu.php`:

```
<?php
// A simple menu builder with options :)

class Menu {
    public $ID;
    public $Buttons = array();
    
    // Adds the button object to the array
    public function Add_Button($btn) {
        array_push($this->Buttons, $btn);
    }
    
    // Returns the string to be echoed inside the html
    public function get() {
        $starter = "<nav id='$this->ID'><ul>";
        
        // loops through each button
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($this->Buttons); $x++) {
            $btn = $this->Buttons[$x];
            $starter .= $btn->get_button(); // <-- Here is where the error is being thrown
            /*
            Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_button() 
            on string in F:\Imagine\Youth Group Connect\Site\php\Menu.php:17 Stack trace
            : #0 F:\Imagine\Youth Group Connect\Site\users\login.php(148): Menu->get() #1 
            {main} thrown in F:\Imagine\Youth Group Connect\Site\php\Menu.php*/
        }
        
        $starter .= "</ul></nav>";
        return $starter;
    }
    
    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->ID = $id;
    }
}

class Button {
    public $link;
    public $text;
    // Whether is the "primary" button or not... I know terrible naming
    public $isBig = false;
    public $subMenu = array();
    
    public function get_button() {
        if ($this->isBig) {
            return "<li><a href='$this->link' class='button primary'>$this->text</a></li>";
        } else if (count($this->subMenu) < 1) {
            return "<li><a href='$this->link'>$this->text</a></li>";
        } else {
            $fullText = "<li><a href='$this->link'>$this->text</a><ul>";
            
            foreach ($this->subMenu as $btn) {
                $fullText .= "<li><a href='$btn->link'>$btn->text</a></li>";
            }
            
            $fullText .= "</ul></li>";
            return $fullText;
        }
    }
    
    public function __construct($link, $text) {
        $this->link = $link;
        $this->text = $text;
    }
    
    // Adds sub-menu items to the button
    public function add_sub_item($link, $text) {
        $this->isBig = false;
        array_push($this->subMenu, new Button($link, $text));
    }
}
?>
```

And then here's from `login.php` where I'm calling it.

```
$menu = new Menu("nav");
$menu->Add_Button(new Button("../index.html", "Home"));

$dropDown = new Button("#", "Download");
$dropDown->add_sub_item("#", "iTunes");
$dropDown->add_sub_item("#", "Play Store");
$dropDown->add_sub_item("#", "Other");

$menu->Add_Button($dropDown);
$menu->Add_Button("#", "Features");

$bigButton = new Button("login.php", "Login/Register");
$bigButton->isBig = true;

$menu->Add_Button($bigButton);
echo $menu->get();
```

Comment: `$btn`, on that line, is a string. Meaning whatever you passed to `Add_Button` must have been one too. Note: you should post your code directly here (as reduced as possible), instead of posting a pastebin. It's not *that* long a chunk.

Comment: @Jeto I'll edit with the paste bin code and the code calling this too.

Comment: `$menu->Add_Button("#", "Features");` <- there you go, you're adding a string there. You probably want `$menu->Add_Button(new Button("#", "Features"));` instead.

Comment: @Jeto thank you, that did it :) A slight oversight.